# delete empty nodes from tree

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

I want to implement a function which deletes any empty children in a tree:

```
makeUnhollow (Node 5 Empty Empty) => Leaf 5
makeUnhollow (Leaf 5) => Leaf 5
makeUnhollow (Node 5 (Leaf 4) Empty) => (Node 5 (Leaf 4) Empty)
```

This is my current code:

```
makeUnhollow :: Tree a -> Tree a
makeUnhollow  (Node a Empty Empty)= Leaf a
makeUnhollow (Leaf a) = Leaf a
makeUnhollow a = a
```

But somehow I'm getting failures for this code:

```
Tests.hs:130:
wrong result
expected: Node 6 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 7)
but got: Node 6 (Node 5 Empty Empty) (Node 7 Empty Empty)
```

Comment: `makeUnhollow` currently doesn't recurse into the tree. Make it recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting *all* `Empty` children in a tree seems a little difficult:

- `Node a Empty Empty` can become `Leaf a`
- What if your root node is `Empty`?
- What will `Node a Empty (Leaf b)` be?

I understand from your test that your goal is just to turn `Node a Empty Empty` into `Leaf a`, and not care when only one child is `Empty`. Mark Seemann's suggestion to turn `makeUnhollow` into a recursive function means you have to make it call itself in the last case of:

```hs
makeUnhollow :: Tree a -> Tree a
makeUnhollow (Node a Empty Empty) = Leaf a
makeUnhollow (Leaf a) = Leaf a
makeUnhollow Empty = ?                --  don't forget to match Empty
makeUnhollow (Node a left right) = ?  --  recurse on left, right :: Tree a
```

I might just call the function `unhollow` since that's an imperative verb, too.

Comment: or even "unhollowed", for a more *declarative* feel to it. :)

Comment: What if `left` and `right` both unhollow to `Empty` in the recursive case?